# How do I solve working around "Models maximum content length exceeded" errors

Tags: openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, py-langchain, langchain-js

I am using LangChain and OpenAI to interract with my postgres database.  It works well on small databases.  But when the database is larger (say over 10K rows), I get the following error

`This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 5100 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages`

An example public database that shows this error is the `MindsDB` real estate database:

```
postgresql+psycopg2://demo_user:demo_password@REDACTED:5432/demo
```

My code is below... this python code can connect to any postgres database and allow you to chat with it, but it fails as noted above on larger databases

```
import sys
from langchain import OpenAI
from langchain import SQLDatabase
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain

import environ
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

API_KEY = env('OPENAI_API_KEY')

if API_KEY == "":
    print("Missing OpenAPI key")
    exit()

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Missing db connection string.  Example 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:1234@localhost:6667/mydb'")
    exit()

dbstring = sys.argv[1]

print("Using OpenAPI with key ["+API_KEY+"] and Database ["+dbstring+"]")

# Setup database
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(
    dbstring,
)

# setup llm
llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=1000,
    openai_api_key=API_KEY)

# Create db chain
QUERY = """
Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct postgresql query to run, then look at the results of the query and return the answer.
Use the following format:

Question: Question here
SQLQuery: SQL Query to run
SQLResult: Result of the SQLQuery
Answer: Final answer here

{question}
"""

# Setup the database chain
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=llm, database=db, verbose=True)

def get_prompt():
    print("Type 'exit' to quit")

    while True:
        prompt = input("Enter a prompt: ")

        if prompt.lower() == 'exit':
            print('Exiting...')
            break
        else:
            try:
                question = QUERY.format(question=prompt)
                print(db_chain.run(question))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

get_prompt()
```

Comment: use try changing max_tokens=4097

Comment: That makes it break even for small databases now.  There is something else about how many tokens in total can be sent... I just don't know how to break things down

Answer (score 0):

You can you this split_query method to chunk you data..you can modify it based on your requirement. Also you have to make sure the contextual details are not lost when you chunk the data. You can try few options (splitting or playing with max tokens) so that it works for your use case

```
        def split_query(query, max_tokens):

            tokens = query.split()
            chunks = []
            chunk = []
            for token in tokens:
                if len(chunk) + len(token) > max_tokens:
                    chunks.append(" ".join(chunk))
                    chunk = []
                chunk.append(token)
            if chunk:
                chunks.append(" ".join(chunk))
            return chunks

        def get_prompt():
            print("Type 'exit' to quit")

            while True:
                prompt = input("Enter a prompt: ")

                if prompt.lower() == 'exit':
                    print('Exiting...')
                    break
                else:
                    try:
                        query = prompt
                        chunks = split_query(query, 4097)
                        for chunk in chunks:
                            question = QUERY.format(question=chunk)
                            print(db_chain.run(question))
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

        get_prompt()
```

Comment: This attempts to split the input question... which isn't that large.  Typically less than 10 words.  The issue is with the size of the database... the number of tables and entries in the database is what causes the error, not the user prompt/question.

Comment: you can use chain.top_k = 0.9 to make model generate text similar to prompt, you need to refine your prompt so that LLM generates output within context limit 4097. Other option would be to change the LLM model that will generate more precise output basis your prompt

Comment: Could you show me exactly what you mean by that?  What do I change in the code?

Comment: This is just an example 

model = ChatVertexAI(
    temperature=1,
    max_output_tokens=1,
    top_p=1,
    top_k=1,
)